# difference between stack segment and uninitialized data segment

Tags: c

I was trying to get a hand over the memory allocation in c.

According to the [following link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/), the stack and the uninitialized data segment are different and the uninitialized data of the local function goes to the uninitialized data segment.

If that is the case then what is stored in the stack segment in case of a code with uninitialized local variables? Is it empty?

Comment: Only stack-allocated data goes into the stack — non-static local variables. That applies whether the variables are initialized or not. Static local variables go in the data segment.  They might be in the BSS section if they're not explicitly initialized, or in the initialized part of the data segment if they're initialized to non-zero values.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend reading "geeksforgeeks" tutorials. You have some misconceptions.

What they call "uninitialized data", the `.bss` segment, is in fact a store for variables of static storage duration that are *zero-initialized*. Including any such variable which is explicitly initialized to value zero.
An explanation of static storage duration and the different common segments, with examples, can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller/237759#237759).

*Only* variables with static storage duration end up in `.bss` and `.data`. Local variables always end up on the stack, or in CPU registers, no matter if they are initialized or not.

(Please note that none of this is specified by the ISO C standard, but rather by industry de facto standards.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "static storage duration" ? So the local static uninitialized variable end up in .data right?

Comment: @nalinkanoongo Everything is explained in the link posted.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: "Including any such variable which is explicitly initialised to value zero.". Large footnote here. Various toolchains have changed their mind on this a few times and different systems may configure this differently. Got bitten by it after having updated either gcc or ld or whatever it was and a method to binary patch a kernel no longer worked (we were dumping a ramdisk image into a large array in the kernel and the toolchain moved it from data to bss). I know that some systems explicitly changed the default behavior of the toolchain when they ran into similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

> *the uninitialized data of the local function goes to the uninitialized data segment.*

Well, that is not entirely true.

Read carefully, ([from the same link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/), emphasis mine)

> [...] uninitialized data starts at the end of the data segment and **contains all global variables and static variables that are initialized to zero or do not have explicit initialization in source code.** [...]

So, the automatic storage variables still resides in stack segment, irrespective of the fact whether they are initialized or not.

*That said, a word of caution, this is "A typical memory representation", not universal. C standard does not mandate to have a stack segment (or any other), for the matter.*